How do I make a section that starts on the left side of the screen and does not reach the right side of the screen?
I'm trying to convert a Figma design, one of the sections of the site looks like in the image, it looks simple enough. However, when trying to implement this section on the site, I ran into problems:
How to implement for the container (background in the attached image) restrictions on height, width and position on the page to make it look like on the design? In addition, the question is how to implement on the left side of the image this... pattern? I would appreciate help from more experienced developers.
I am using Next.js, Typescript and TailwindCSS as my stack. I am also attaching the code of my section where I tried to solve the problem -
SafeSection.tsx:
"use client";

import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import '../../app/[locale]/globals.css';

export interface SafeSectionProps {
    imageSrc: string;
    imageAlt: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imagePosition: 'left' | 'right';
}

const SafeSection: React.FC<SafeSectionProps> = ({
    imageSrc,
    imageAlt,
    title,
    description,
    imagePosition
}) => {
    return (
        <section className="lg:bg-[#495057] rounded-e-xl lg:mt-32 mt-36 flex justify-center items-center text-pretty">
            <div className="bg-[#495057] relative hidden md:flex lg:hidden h-[484px] w-[30dvw] justify-center items-start"></div>
            <div className={`bg-[#495057] lg:bg-transparent p-6 lg:p-14 mr-[13dvw] lg:mr-0 rounded-e-lg flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap max-w-[85rem] w-full ${imagePosition === 'right' ? 'flex-row-reverse' : ''}`}>
                <div className={`relative w-full lg:w-1/2 h-[300px] lg:h-[500px] -mt-32 mb-8 lg:mb-0 ${imagePosition === 'left' ? '-ml-8 lg:-ml-16' : '-mr-8 lg:-mr-16'}`}>
                    <Image
                        src={imageSrc}
                        alt={imageAlt}
                        fill
                        className="rounded-lg object-cover"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="w-full lg:w-1/2 text-white px-4 lg:px-10">
                    <h2 className="text-3xl lg:text-5xl font-bold mb-4 text-center lg:text-left">
                        {title}
                    </h2>
                    <p className="text-xl lg:text-2xl text-left">
                        {description}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default SafeSection;

I tried using flex and using margin/padding to set the section position. But then the content was not in the middle of the container (with max width 85rem). Also, the container (with dark background) did not stretch from the leftmost edge, i.e. on very large screens, the section would look very small and lose position. Unfortunately, nothing helped....
UPD 1.0: Here's the Codesandbox project. Also wanted to say that I need to keep the section adaptable for different devices. And also, need to place the Rune.png to the left of the image to create a nice "pattern" for my container

can you prepare fiddle so we can also debug it? you can use https://jsfiddle.net/ TS options to create one.

@burcu Hi, I've updated my question, added a link to Codesandbox and a brief description of what I need to implement
